# angular ui-bootstrap $modal injection fail

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I use angular 1.5 and the last bootstrap & ui-bootstrap versions.

I want to interger [angular-confirm](http://schlogen.github.io/angular-confirm/) module in my application but i don't found the required `modal`

> Usage
>
> This module depends on Angular-UI bootstrap for its $modal service

For example this fail:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-confirm'])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope , $modal , $confirm) {
});
```

> Error: $injector:unpr
>   Unknown Provider
>
> Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal <- $confirm

*Where can i download `$modal` because it is not in `angular-ui-bootstrap.js` ?*

What i'm missing ?

I create a plunkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/WpM3D0vZLMnjgjaESasV?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest versions of angular-bootstrap (>= 0.14), [`$modal` has been renamed to `$uibModal`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/8c7b9e4), so you need to inject that one:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope , $uibModal , $confirm) {
    ...
```

The documentation of angular-confirm has not been adjusted.

Comment: yes thank you. In fact i didn't need to inject $uib-modal. the code of the example in angular-confirm is not up to date ( the one from their github was and use directly $uib-modal )

Comment: Nice, but I think you mean $uibModal not $uib-modal. The uib-modal syntax is from the associated CSS.